# How to Install DebugKit on CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm learning how to work with `CakePHP` and I configured everything allright, but now, I get this warning:

`DebugKit is not installed. It will help you inspect and debug different aspects of your application. You can install it from github`

I already clicked on that link, and downloaded that app, but I have no idea where to place these folders... I'm using **EasyPhp** as my web host.
Also [Here](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) I followed the steps,
and there is:

```
`Ensure the plugin is loaded in app/Config/bootstrap.php by calling CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');`
```

But I don't know how to `call` something here, is there a prompt ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

***How to Install DebugKit for CakePHP (in just 4 easy steps!):***

**STEP 1 (option A): The traditional / download method:**

Create a `DebugKit` folder within your `app/Plugin` directory, and put the contents of the download into it (not the top-level folder - the stuff within it).  If you know how to clone from github, that works fine also.

---

**STEP 1 (option B): The Composer method**

This seems to currently be the most popular option (and for good reason).  If you're already using [Composer [find out more about it here]](http://getcomposer.org/), then adding DebugKit is crazy-simple.  If you haven't used Composer before, don't worry - just use "option A" above.  The end-result is the same, and it's easy too.

> Ensure require is present in composer.json. This will install the
>   plugin into Plugin/DebugKit:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

---

**STEP 2:**

Then, in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php`, add (or un-comment) the following line:

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
```

Lastly, in your `app/Controller/AppController.php` file (within the class), add:

```
public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

(If you already have a `$components` array, then just add to it - don't re-set it.)

---

**STEP 3: Ensure debug is 1 or more**

In your `Config/core.php` file, make sure this line:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

has a value of 1 or 2.  [(read more about debug mode here)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#update-core-php)

---

**STEP 4: Remove `sql_dump`:**

In your layout file, remove the 'sql_dump' element (at the bottom of the default layout)

---

**According to the "Installation" section on the [debugKit page](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit):**

- Clone/Copy the files in this directory into app/Plugin/DebugKit
- Ensure the plugin is loaded in app/Config/bootstrap.php by calling CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
- Include the toolbar component in your AppController.php:
  public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
- Set debug mode to at least 1.
- Make sure to remove the 'sql_dump' element from your layout if you want to experience the awesome that is the debug kit SQL log.

---

**How do I know if it's working?**

You should see a small icon on a gray square in the upper right corner of your site.  Click on this to expand the options, then click on an option to start being awesome.

Comment: So when it says "call" that method I updated in my question is just to un-comment ? How do I start to set codes here ? I'm new with web, even more with CakePHP (it's a work for my course). Hope you could give me a hand, really thank you Dave!

Comment: Worked perfect !! Thanks, Could you just answer me the last comment ? just for me get used to it.

Comment: Saying "calling" is similar to saying "writing", but usually refers to writing some code that tells your program to access a function or method.

Comment: I add this and I get error:  
`class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array(
   'DebugKit.Toolbar`
};`

Comment: Thanks man !! Omg , I cant believe i was that stupid !! MyBad hehe, I have to say i was starting to think if it was for me or not (programming...) Thanks Dave !

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - np - we all have our days :)

Answer (score 1):

in the root application folder: go to `\vendor\cakephp\` copy the folder `debug_kit` and paste it in `\plugins` folder, this worked for me in a heroku deployment (not production, only for development)

Answer (score 0):

its simply a version problem. download the compatible version of DebugKit it should run without any error. confirmed!