# CakePhp: Can't get DebugKit plugin to work

Tags: debugging, cakephp, plugins

Even following [this awesome guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp) i couldn't get DebugKit to work on a clean cakephp installation.
The error said that DebugKit Plugin was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to explicity tell CakePhp in which folder the plugins are.

Writing the following code in the **app/core.php** file:

> App::build(array( 
>         'Plugin' => array(ROOT . '/app/Plugin')  ));

Comment: That's probably a sign of having installed CakePHP in a non-normal location, or in some non-standard way.