# Installing Cakephp DebugKit

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, configuration

I have had difficulty getting DebugKit configured with CakePHP.  I've read the answer here: [How to Install DebugKit on CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp)   but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Here is what I have done so far:

Created a directory called DebugKit in app/Plugin

Downloaded all the files from Git (They come in a folder called debug_kit but I just copied all the files in that folder and placed them in my newly created DebugKit folder)

Uncommented the line  CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit in Bootstrap.php

My AppController Class now looks like this

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

}
```

My Core.php has this line:

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

And I have commented out this line in the file default.ctp

```
<!-- <?php //echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> -->
```

The error message I receive is:

> Error: The application is trying to load a file from the DebugKit
>   plugin
>
> Error: Make sure your plugin DebugKit is in the app\Plugin directory
>   and was loaded

I have been URL Rewriting enabled as per these instructions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

And my Web application directory structure looks like this: 
Wamp/www/cakephp/

I also notice that there is a folder called plugins at this location: 
cakephp/plugins  - I have tried copying the downloaded plugin to that location but it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

L

Comment: If you are using cakephp2.x, you need to load the plugin manually in bootstrap.php file.
CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
CakePlugin::load(’DebugKit’); //Loads a single plugin

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but I have already configured that in the bootstrap.php file.  I've tried both loading just a single plugin and using the loadAll() as well.

Comment: You can also delete the cache files,  just to be sure

Answer (score 2):

This was a very silly mistake of mine - I had just uncommented the line CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); in the bootstrap.php file but it was still surrounded by a comment block, so uncommenting the line took no effect. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cakephp2.x, you need to load the plugin  in cake/app/config/ bootstrap.php file.

you will find the lines will look like

```
*CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once *CakePlugin::load(’DebugKit’); //Loads a single plugin
```

then you have to copy paste the code without the * symbol

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once CakePlugin::load(’DebugKit’); //Loads a single plugin
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the name of directory where debugkit resides

the right name is DebugKit

app/Plugin/DebugKit