# CakePHP DebugKit Plugin Toolbar doesn't appear after Install

Tags: cakephp, plugins, installation, toolbar

Hello and thanks in advance for your help! Multiple attempts at installation of CakePHP's DebugKit Plugin unsuccessful

Steps Attempted:
1. Download and and unzipped debug_kit (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)
2. Renamed file to "DebugKit" and moved to /webroot/cakephp/plugins (so that its inside the plugins folder).
3. Made the following modifications to the appropriate files. (I've double and triple checked these)

````
# Installation

* Clone/Copy the files in this directory into `app/Plugin/DebugKit`
* Ensure the plugin is loaded in `app/Config/bootstrap.php` by calling `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');`
* Include the toolbar component in your `app/Controller/AppController.php`:
```php
class AppController extends Controller {
         public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
}
```
* Set `Configure::write('debug', 1);` in `app/Config/core.php`.
* Make sure to remove the 'sql_dump' element from your layout (usually
  `app/View/Layouts/default.ctp` if you want to experience the awesome that is
  the debug kit SQL log.
````

When I got to my localhost/cakephp I see the other notifications and I have everything else configured so that they appear green. However Cakephp doesn't even see that I'm attempting to use the DebugKit plugin and the toolbar is not displayed.

I am new to CakePHP and have been working through tutorials to get everything set up correctly. I thought that the DebugKit would be incredibly helpful in helping me understand CakePHP. I have gone through several tutorials and searched the internet but I have been unable to get it to work. If you have any ideas please let me know!

NOTE:
CakePHP Version 2.4.6
DebugKit 2.2.1 (also tried newer version)
LAMP install on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Have you tried to read ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp

Comment: Did you change permissions on your folder in plugins?

Comment: @Dezigo, yes that is one of the tutorials I used to try to install it,  along with one from Lynda.com and some other websites.

Comment: @skywalker, Thanks for your suggestion. I check my permissions for my folders in plugins and they are all set to 775 which should be sufficient. I tried changing them to 777 just to see but unfortunately  it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try to add in bootstrap.php: CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');

Comment: @Dezigo I already included CakePlugin::load('DebugKit') in my bootstrap.php as well as all of the other lines of code to add and comment out as mentioned in the install guide you listed above.

Comment: "When I got to my localhost/cakephp I see the other notifications and I have everything else configured so that they appear green" - Can you post a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 0):

1. In cakePHP root directory > plugins' folder, that is where DebugKit should stay.
2. Then you need to make the kit available to everybody by loading it in bootstrap. In app > config > bootstrap.php add this line;

```
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
```