# Debugkit doesn't show toolbar

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, installation

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492806/cakephp-debugkit-plugin-toolbar-doesnt-appear-after-install) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp) too. i followed all steps that is mentioned on these links. In my case, debug kit it appears along the page and not in a side bar like it should. What am i missing? It seems that is js or css that is failing. I'm using cakephp 2.4.7 and debugkit 2.2.3.
My steps were:

```
 - Clone/Copy the files in this directory into app/Plugin/DebugKit

 - Ensure the plugin is loaded in app/Config/bootstrap.php by calling CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');

 - Include the toolbar component in your AppController.php: public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

 - Set debug mode equal 2.
 - Remove the 'sql_dump' element from default layout.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a issue with your server...Mostly with your mod_rewrite..

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find my issue. date_default_timezone_set() is not defined. it appears:

> DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for 'WEST/1.0/DST' instead

For that reason you must to uncomment line 270 in your core.php.