# Error: The application is trying to load a file from the DebugKit plugin

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP DebugKit Install
CakePHP 2.5.6
DebugKit 2.2.5

I followed the manual install directions at: [GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)  These are pretty much the same directions from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp).

I get the following error:

### Missing Plugin

**Error:** 
    The application is trying to load a file from the *DebugKit* plugin


    **Error:** 
    Make sure your plugin DebugKit is in the app/Plugin directory and was loaded

```
<?php
CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
```

**Loading all plugins:** 
    If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app/Config/bootstrap.php file

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

**Notice:** 
    If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_plugin.ctp

I tried changing my permissions on the folders:

```
[dskidmore_it@InternalWeb DebugKit]$ pwd
/var/www/html/cake2.5.6/app/Plugin/DebugKit
[dskidmore_it@InternalWeb DebugKit]$ ls -al
total 76
drwxrwxr-x. 10 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 17:10 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root         root          4096 Nov 24 16:52 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  1002 Nov 22 12:58 composer.json
drwxrwxr-x.  3 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Console
drwxrwxr-x.  3 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Controller
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it   114 Nov 22 12:58 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  5722 Nov 22 12:58 .jshintrc
drwxrwxr-x.  4 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Lib
drwxrwxr-x.  7 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Locale
drwxrwxr-x.  3 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Model
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it 12210 Nov 22 12:58 README.md
drwxrwxr-x.  4 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 Test
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  2398 Nov 22 12:58 .travis.yml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it     6 Nov 22 12:58 VERSION.txt
drwxrwxr-x.  5 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 View
drwxrwxr-x.  5 dskidmore_it dskidmore_it  4096 Nov 24 16:51 webroot
```

I'm guessing it's a permissions issue?

Comment: The intern fixed this without telling me how, then the project got canceled...  I'd guess that the group or owner needed to be changed to match the webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it; i was using oven 3.5 when running php 5.6 so i upgraded to php 7 and everything installed perfectly

Comment: Were you the intern from 2015?!