# CakePHP 2.6 DebugKit not loading properly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-debug-kit

So I recently tried to install DebugKit for cakephp 2.6 and run into an interesting propblem. I have loaded the plugin in bootstrap.php. I have debug set to 1 in core.php. I have the component loaded in AppController.php. And I have removed the sql_dump from default.ctp. When I load my app I don't see the cake logo in the upper right corner and I get a message that prints at the bottom of the page that says.

```
There are no active panels. You must enable a panel to see its output.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code in files as requested:

bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load( [ 'DebugKit', 'BoostCake', 'Search' ] );
```

core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

AppController.php

```
public $helpers = [
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Html',
        'Form',
        'Paginator' => [ 'className' => 'BoostCake.BoostCakePaginator' ],
    ]
```

Comment: What you have set in your component ?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp) if this can help.

Comment: I checked the post previous to posting this and followed all of these steps.

Comment: post your code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I saw my problem as soon as I posted my code.

I declared the Debugkit.Toolbar in the helpers array not the components array so now I have

```
$components = [ 'DebugKit.Toolbar' ];
```

And everything works just fine.  Thank you to everyone who posted