# CakePHP3: cannot get matching working properly

Tags: cakephp, associations, filtering, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

If I write the following query:

```
$sites = $this->Sites->find()
->contain(['Agthemes'])
->matching('Agthemes', function ($q) {
    return $q->where([
        'Agthemes.site_id IS NOT' => null
    ]);
})
->all();
```

I only get `Sites` which have existing `Agthemes`.

Now I write a similar query but with one additional association level:

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all')
->contain([
    'Sites.Agthemes'
])
->matching('Sites.Agthemes', function ($q) {
    return $q->where([
        'Agthemes.site_id IS NOT' => null
    ]);
})
->distinct(['Users.id'])
->limit(5)
->all();
```

And in that case, I also get `Sites` with empty `Agthemes`.
Could you tell me why?

**EDIT**

I add the relationships

SitesTable

```
    $this->hasMany('Agthemes', [
        'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
        'joinTable' => 'sites_users',
    ]);
```

UsersTable

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Sites', [
        'targetForeignKey' => 'site_id',
        'joinTable' => 'sites_users',
    ]);
```

AgthemesTable

```
    $this->belongsTo('Sites');
```

Answer (score 0):

In DebugKit, look at the queries being run. Using 'contain' often runs completely separate queries, then combines the results (depends on the association type).

If you want to be sure **to limit the results based on conditions against an associated model, use 'joins' instead of 'contain'.**

See this page for details about how the associations use (or don't use) joins, and how you can change the join strategy...etc:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: my problem here is that I cannot get DebugKit Toolbar displayed. It seems Debugkit working anyway as I get an error if I change its folder name. I'm working on a subdomain (test.myweb.com) I saw many posts about that problem, I think I checked everything, I cannot see any error in logs nor in firebug !?!

Comment: the thing I'm not sure about between different versions is if we have to write `public $components = ['DebugKit.Toolbar'];` as you said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124398/how-to-install-debugkit-on-cakephp) but I think it's cakePHP2 related and I didn't see such thing [here](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Controller/AppController.php)

Comment: Not getting DebugKit to work is certainly a problem, but should be it's own question including all the details.

Comment: I understand but I got working in fact. I had a problem with a folder's rights. I'm now going to investigate in this problem.